BirthDate column to be masked in SSIS
Source table and destination table is from SQL Server databases. I need a derived column expression
for BirthDate in the format YY--** (Example : 19XX-XX-XX)
getting errors while converting
Expecting BirthDate column to be masked without conversion errors.

SQL Server offers dynamic masking, including masks for dates that ensure the values are masked even if the column is included in the results by mistake

Dates are binary values, not strings, and have no format. Returning a string changes the type and can't be used in any UI that correctly works with dates. A better choice would be to do what SQL Server does, and return an actual, possibly dummy, date. By default SQL Server returns 1900-01-01 as the masked value

I want a  derived column expression in ssis

Why do you want it in SSIS? Assume you're working to people that use SSIS for decades. The why matters a lot. Masking is used when reading, not writing. SSIS itself will complain if you change a date to a string too. If you want to read masked data, use DATEFROMPARTS(100*(DATEPART(YYYY,BirthDay)/100),1,1) in the source query. If you want to create a CSV with masked data, that's the safest and fastest option.

If you can't do that (big why?) you can use the same logic, using YEAR(BirthDate) to get the year. Something like ((DT_WSTR, 2)YEAR(BirthDate)/100) + 'XX-XX-XX'. That would be useful if you wanted to export to a CSV that must have this specific format instead of 1900-01-01 or 2000-01-01

Adding a derived column doesn't protect against accidental inclusion of the unmasked column in a query, or through SQL injection. Other derived columns can still reveal the original BirthDate too.
Dates are binary values and have no format too. Returning a string instead of an actual data can create problems in client applications eg in data binding to date columns in a grid.
As an SSIS derived column transformation
First of all, it's safer to mask the data at the source query, as the other options show. Using a derived column transformation is only useful when exporting data to file formats that must have the 19xx-xx-xx format. The source column will have to be removed too, to avoid accidental leaks.
The logic is the same as the other options. Extract the Year part, calculate the century and construct the final value with eg :
((DT_WSTR, 2)YEAR(BirthDate)/100) + 'XX-XX-XX'

If the century part isn't wanted, you can just hard-code the string 19XX-XX-XX
Without Dynamic Masking
You can return a masked real date value similar to what SQL Server does using DATEFROMPARTS, eg :
SELECT 
    BirthDate, 
    DATEFROMPARTS(100*(DATEPART(YYYY,BirthDay)/100),1,1) As MaskedBirthDate
...

You'll have to ensure unprivileged users can't query BirthDate using column permissions or restricting access to specific, masked views though.
With Dynamic Masking
SQL Server offers dynamic masking, including masks for dates that ensure the values are masked even if the column is included in the results by mistake. The default scheme is to return the actual date value 1900-01-01 to users that have no permission.
The doc example shows how to create a table with masked columns using different patterns :
CREATE TABLE Data.Membership (
    MemberID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    FirstName VARCHAR(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1, "xxxxx", 1)') NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(12) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()') NOT NULL,
    DiscountCode SMALLINT MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'random(1, 100)') NULL,
    BirthDay DATETIME MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL
);

In SQL Server 2019 you can assign the UNMASK privilege at the database level with eg :
GRANT UNMASK TO ServiceManager;

In SQL Server 2022 and later you can assign UNMASK for specific columns
GRANT UNMASK ON object::Data.Membership(FirstName) TO ServiceAttendant;

The same query will return different results for different users.
Notice that I included the "masking" expression in both queries, to show that function calls only see the masked value, not the original  :
EXECUTE AS USER = 'ServiceLead';

SELECT MemberID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, BirthDay,DATEFROMPARTS(100*(DATEPART(YYYY,BirthDay)/100),1,1)
FROM Data.Membership;

REVERT;

go
EXECUTE AS USER = 'ServiceManager';

SELECT MemberID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, BirthDay,DATEFROMPARTS(100*(DATEPART(YYYY,BirthDay)/100),1,1)
FROM Data.Membership;

REVERT;
GO

These two return :
MemberID    FirstName   LastName    Phone   Email   BirthDay    (No column name)
1   Rxxxxxo Tamburello  xxxx    RXXX@XXXX.com   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01
2   Jxxxxxe Galvin      xxxx    JXXX@XXXX.com   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01
3   Sxxxxxi Menon       xxxx    SXXX@XXXX.com   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01
4   Zxxxxxg Mu          xxxx    ZXXX@XXXX.com   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01

And
MemberID    FirstName   LastName    Phone   Email   BirthDay    (No column name)
1   Roberto Tamburello  555.123.4567    RTamburello@contoso.com 1985-01-25 03:25:05.000 1900-01-01
2   Janice  Galvin      555.123.4568    JGalvin@contoso.com.co  1990-05-14 11:30:00.000 1900-01-01
3   Shakti  Menon       555.123.4570    SMenon@contoso.net  2004-02-29 14:20:10.000 2000-01-01
4   Zheng   Mu          555.123.4569    ZMu@contoso.net 1990-03-01 06:00:00.000 1900-01-01

With Dynamic Masking enabled, the derived column only sees the masked value, not the original.

We can use the CONVERT() function here, assuming that your BirthDate column is date/datetime:
SELECT BirthDate, CONVERT(varchar(2), BirthDate, 120) + 'XX-XX-XX' AS MaskedBirthDate
FROM yourTable;


i want a derived column expression in ssis

I want a derived column expression in ssis

@Syed this will work in SSIS, in the source query. Why do you want it as a transformation instead?
